# EntityType 'GlobalAction' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Estoy tratando de modificar una Aplicación Web en la cuál usa EntityFramework.
Hace unos meses cuando la abrí por última vez (hace unos 2 meses aproximadamente) funcionaba sin problemas, pero ahora me da esta excepción que dice que la tabla GlobalAction no tiene definida una clave primaria. Esta tabla no se modifica hace años, por lo que no encuentro motivo para que deje de funcionar de un momento a otro.

Esta es la definición de la tabla:

```
public partial class GlobalAction
{
    public GlobalAction()
    {
        this.GlobalActionItems = new HashSet<GlobalActionItems>();
        this.GlobalActionPerRole = new HashSet<GlobalActionPerRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int gaID { get; set; }
    public string gaDescripcion { get; set; }
    public bool gaEstado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GlobalActionItems> GlobalActionItems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GlobalActionPerRole> GlobalActionPerRole { get; set; }
}
```

El campo gaID es la clave de la tabla.
Alguien puede ayudarme a resolver esto?

Comment: como lograste que la clase se llame `indise_GlobalAction` pero el constructor solo `GlobalAction` ?

Comment: En realidad todo se llama indise_GlobalAction, pero quise poner solo GlobalAction acá para poder verlo mejor y me olvidé de cambiarle el nombre a la clase jajaja, ahí lo edité

Comment: también puede deberse a otro tipo de cambios, como la versión de entity framework u otros, mira qué cosas genéricas has cambiado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que pudieron haber cambiado las condiciones por las cuales aplique las convenciones en el mapping de la entidad

[Convenciones de Code First](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in)

Si analizamos la documentacion, alli se menciona

> Convención de clave principal
>
> Código infiere en primer lugar que una propiedad es una clave principal si una propiedad en una clase se denomina "ID" (no distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas) o el nombre de la clase seguido por "ID". Si el tipo de la propiedad de clave principal es numérico o GUID estará configurado como una columna de identidad.

En tu caso definir como nombre `gaID` no aplica esa convencion, salvo que hayas mapeado explicitamente indicando que es la key de la entidad

Sino deberias cambiarlo a solo

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

o sino

```
public int GlobalActionID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sólo le puse `ID` como nombre y funcionó (también tendré que cambiar otras tablas), pero lo que no entiendo es por qué motivo antes funcionaba y de un momento a otro dejó de hacerlo si la tabla no tiene cambios desde hace mucho tiempo?

Comment: quizas lo habian mapeado explictamente en el dbcontext usando el `HasKey()` entonces si puede poner un nombre diferente en la propiedad que es la key https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#configuring-a-primary-key